# How do you calm down startled animals so they can be killed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Since animals all run faster than you, and at Legendary difficulty, have tons of health, I really don't have a chance at killing one unless I double dagger sneak attack them.  However, once they are startled by *something*, they fly off and I lose a delicious soul and some hides.

How do I calm down a fleeing/running animal so I can kill it?

Comment: I thought this was [outdoors.se] for a second there

Comment: @mikeTheLiar From which follows, "How do you suppress the natural survival instinct in animals"?  Alternately, we know humans can outrun every other animal *in the long term* so you could just chase it until it wears out.

Comment: [Kyne's Peace](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kyne's_Peace) is designed *specifically* for this purpose.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [Kyne's Peace](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Kyne's_Peace) shout which,

> will calm all wild animals, except frost trolls, within the range of approximately 100 paces.

or you can use one of the calming [illusion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illusion) spells Calm, Pacify, or Harmony which prevents animals or people up to a certain level from fighting. Also, as @WillihamTotland pointed out, Courage and Rally will make the animals run towards you instead of fleeing.

Another tactic you could try is using the [paralyze](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Paralyze_(Skyrim)) spell or [ice form](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_Form) shout to prevent them from running while you hack at them.

If you are simply not doing enough damage, there is the old trick of becoming a [stealth archer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQLSx.png), because sneaky archers do a lot of damage, and who hunts animals with daggers? All proper hunters use a bow.

Comment: Also, Courage and Rally will work, and make the animals run _towards_ you.

Comment: I stealth-archer'd my way out of Oblivions first dungeon, and in the process I leveled up in stealth and archery. Twice. I was so ridiculous that occasionally I would get in a fight and crouch down and they would forget where I was.

Comment: Legendary difficulty changes the game big time.  Fresh out of Helgen you'll need 8-10 sword hits to kill a **rabbit**.  An Elk is close to a hundred hits.

Comment: @Nelson Paralyze can paralyze something for 10-15 seconds. and you can always paralyze them again. Also you can use poisons on your blade to help kill them faster.

Comment: Paralyze is relatively late game, and if i can get it and cast it at any regularity, i would be able to make paralyze weapons, sell them, and buy hides instead.  I probably don't want to use paralyze poisons for random animals.  I'll rather kill a mammoth instead.

Answer (score 11):

This may be tedious, but you can read all of the stone tablets on the way up to [High Hrothgar](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:High_Hrothgar). This will add the [**Voice of the Sky**](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Voice_of_the_Sky#Voice_of_the_Sky) blessing to your character, which lasts 24 real-time hours (20 in-game days):

> Animals will neither attack nor flee from you.

There are ten stone tablets along the Seven Thousand Steps. They do not need to be read in any particular order.

Comment: Really?!  Wow, I need to check this out right away... bears and saber cats are are so deadly in Legendary... it'll be worth doing this just so I don't randomly die in the wilderness.

Comment: @Nelson I cant remember if the 24 hours is real time or game time, but in either instance you get a while in which all wild animals are just like "yo" whenever you're around. I keep forgetting where all the totems are mind. I think that two of them have worshippers when you go up normally anyway, and that they display the name "pilgrim" or something. Basically, look for the totems they are praying at.

Comment: 5?  No.  I believe there are 10 of them.  As each is numbered, you can see if you've missed one.  Take a peek at the number on the one closest to the monastery if you want the exact count.

Comment: @tjd Yeah as I said I dont recall much about them. I know theyre there and what they do but that is about it. I dont know where they are on the route, nor how many, nor even whos at which one (i know theres a frost troll just before one of them... and two worshippers further down but thats about it.)

Comment: Did some further testing. **The effect is removed if you actually *kill* any animal** (though not other creatures). Hence, this would be useful for avoiding dangerous wildlife encounters but not for hunting (and therefore is not a correct answer to your question). In that case, use the Kyne's Peace shout or the Illusion spells mentioned by Dragonrage's answer instead.

Comment: @bwDraco aw really? that sucks. I dont remember that being the case... oh well. if the spells are unavailable its an 'okay' alternative i suppose but not a proper solution